# Can you deformation retract a sphere to a point?

Tags: general-topology

So, I'm working on a topology problem (Calculating the fundemental group of two spheres adjoined by a single point).  As a subpart of the problem, we're trying to figure out if a sphere by itself can be deformation retracted to a point on the sphere.   (This'll lead to us eventually using mini van Kampen later).  I've seen people say "deform along the meridians",  but my classmates and I aren't seeing/understanding why this is a deformation retract, and we didn't go over it in class.

Comment: No, you cannot deformation retract the sphere onto a point. Since $H_2(S^2) = \mathbb Z$, the sphere is not contractible. However, $S^2$ is simply connected. This should be sufficient for the purpose of applying van Kampen.

Comment: Didn't think so. (Though we haven't done second fundemental groups in our class).   We know the sphere is simply connected,  but the problem is in showing our two overlapping sets are simply connected.  Hrm....wait,  maybe shrink the hemisphere to a point?We can deform retract an open hemisphere to a point, right?

Comment: Yes, you can do so.

Comment: You might want to consider the left sphere + part of the right as $U$, and the right sphere plus part of the left as $V$.

Comment: Problem is solved by doing exactly as @JohnHughes suggested, thanks everyone.